Why is Visual Studio adding the existing project into the .vs folder?
I created a new blank solution in Visual Studio and added an existing project by right clicking the Solution then doing Add -> Existing Project and selecting its .csproj file. Now that I look at my project folder, I see that the existing project I added has all its files and folders inside the .vs folder. Is that normal and why does it happen?

As far as I know Visual Studio is not supposed to copy project and source files to the .vs folder.

No, that is not normal. Your project files should not be in the .vs folder. This folder is used by Visual Studio to store solution-specific information, such as user settings and cache.
What probably happened is that when you selected "Add -> Existing Project", you accidentally navigated to the .vs folder and selected the .csproj file from there.
To fix this, you should move your project out of the .vs folder. Be sure to close Visual Studio before doing so to avoid potential problems. You can then add the project back to your solution from its new location.

I found out that the project folder in my new solution is actually referencing the location where I took the .csproj from.
